# Extract Transaction ID from from column with JSON Array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with a JSON Array and I need to extract transaction_id if there is one:

```
{
  "transaction_id": "222222",
  "feature_id": "e57dcd3c-7adf-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
  "provider_type": "thm",
  "transaction_date": "2020-11-14",
  "account_number": "XXXX",
  "transaction_vendor": "Visa",
  "transaction_type": "DEBIT",
  "alert_type": "Large Card Purchase",
  "threshold_amount": "1250.0",
  "profile_id": "4fbf9b51-c737-434d-ae5c-63a35ac4a75a",
  "alert_id": "d1cd1f80-ed0c-49c3-bf97-e71834f4aaa1",
  "account_name": "BankXX",
  "provider_id": "2",
  "alert_date": "2022-11-05T01:31:17.000Z",
  "create_date": "2022-11-05T01:31:17.000Z"
}
```

Comment: That is a JSON object not a JSON array - did you look at the documentation on JSON methods? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: What version of SQL Server? JSON support makes its entrance in 2016 and with that it's fairly simple, while in earlier versions it's next to impossible without clunky, unreliable hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as this

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[JsonStr] varchar(max))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'{"transaction_id": "222222","feature_id": "e57dcd3c-7adf-11eb-9439-0242ac130002","provider_type": "thm","transaction_date": "2020-11-14","account_number": "XXXX","transaction_vendor": "Visa","transaction_type": "DEBIT","alert_type": "Large Card Purchase","threshold_amount": "1250.0","profile_id": "4fbf9b51-c737-434d-ae5c-63a35ac4a75a","alert_id": "d1cd1f80-ed0c-49c3-bf97-e71834f4aaa1","account_name": "BankXX","provider_id": "2","alert_date": "2022-11-05T01:31:17.000Z","create_date": "2022-11-05T01:31:17.000Z"}')
 
Select ID 
      ,Trans_ID  = json_value(JsonStr,'$.transaction_id')
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ID  Trans_ID
1   222222
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used next:

```
JSON_VALUE(args, '$.transaction_id')
```